# Three.js - Issues with shapes and inside holes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having an issue, how can I obtain a kind of "open ring" like the torus but squared?
I tried with a shape plus a path as a hole:

```
var arcShape = new THREE.Shape();   
arcShape.moveTo( 40, 0 );   
arcShape.arc( 0, 0, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI, false );  

var holePath = new THREE.Path();
holePath.moveTo( 30,0 )
holePath.arc( 0, 0, 30, 0, 2*Math.PI, true );
```

And until now, making a mesh:

```
new THREE.Mesh( arcShape.extrude({ amount: 5, bevelEnabled: false }), MATERIAL );
```

it works, but how to make a middle ring? I mean, with:

```
 var arcShape = new THREE.Shape();  
 arcShape.moveTo( 40, 0 );  
 arcShape.arc( 0, 0, 40, 0, Math.PI, false );   

 var holePath = new THREE.Path();
 holePath.moveTo( 30,0 );
 holePath.arc( 0, 0, 30, 0, Math.PI, true );
```

It works, but it remains a subtle face between the terminal parts... is there a way to make it completely open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than start from square one, try changing the parameters in the Torus geometry constructor:

```
// Torus geometry parameters:
//     radius of entire torus,
//     diameter of tube (should be less than total radius), 
//     segments around radius, 
//     segments around torus ("sides")
var torusGeom = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 25, 10, 4, 4 );
```